# node.js - Mongodb query on text field not returning results

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I have the following query in node.js

```
let rootWords =  await wordCollection.find({wordName: Word.wordName}).toArray();
```

It doesn't return any results when Word.wordName only consists of one character. It works for all other words.

When I execute the query in the mongo shell, however, it works:

```
db.getCollection('Words').find({wordName: "в"})
```

Comment: remove .toArray and try

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work... or rather that way it returns a cursor object. toArray works for other funtions.